# Javascript-Define the file/folder path during file/folder upload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, client

I am implementing a file upload form in Javascript.

Below is my form code:

```
<form action="uploadAction.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="_blank ">
    <input type="file" name="file" webkitdirectory directory>
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

If the user allows disclosing information, I want to append some specific path from an input upload file path, such as `{Full File Path} = {User Folder Path} + {Specific File Path}`.

For example

- User Path: `c:\hello\`
- Specific Path : `~\src\helloworld.java`
- Upload File Path: `c:\hello\src\helloworld.java`

Is it impossible because of user privacy? I know that JSP is only executing on the Client PC, not the server. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about having the "open" dialog box pop up already pointing to a specific folder on the user's machine?

Comment: Nope. I want to define the upload file path by aggrementing user input and specific file path. The path of open dialog box is selected by user.

Comment: I checked that all files in the user input directory are selected after selecting the folder path.However, I want to upload the only one file in the user folder.